# I want to reuse html <button> tag as my own and extend template

Tags: angular

Let's imagine that I have component .

```
template: 
      <button class="my-own-button" (click)='handelClick($event)' [type]='this.type'>
        <app-logo [src]="this.src">
        </app-logo>
        <ng-content>
        </ng-content>
      </button>
  
class MyButtonComponent {
  @Input() src: string = "";
  @Input() type: string = "button";
  @Output() click = new EventEmitter<any>();

  handelClick(event: any){
    this.click.emit(event);
  }
}
```

And I still need to explicitly define the click output and type input props, that already exist in native . I just want to add an src input property and supply some additional into the template.

Is there any way to solve it? If not, could you suggest the best way to solve it?

Comment: maybe it will be much simple with directive?

Comment: I don't get what is your issue, if it's about some data sharing, you can use service.

Comment: It is about how to extend the existing native element. Is it possible to extend the template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing selector of the button component to attribute selector instead of an element selector. That should help in retaining native button tag in your component, while actually being an Angular component. [Angular Material](https://material.angular.io) uses attribute selectors for their [buttons](https://material.angular.io/components/button/overview).

Use `[my-button]` or `[myButton]` instead of `my-button` as the component selector.